# Creating flt (floating point raster) with QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, floating-point

I would like to create a flt (floating point raster) with QGIS to use later as a terrain in Hec RAS RAS-Mapper. With Raster -> Conversion -> Translate there is no option to create a flt. Is there another way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Save your raster as [ESRI .hdr](https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/ehdr.html) with datatype as float32 and file extension as ".flt".

Comment: Tank you Luke, that was what i was searching for. It s working now.

Comment: "BIL" is "Band Interleaved by Line" per https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/raster-and-images/bil-bip-and-bsq-raster-files.htm   It could be important if you want to store multi-band rasters in a .flt file.  Maybe concatenate 3 .flt files together sequentially and edit a .hdr file to set the layout to "BSQ"

Comment: Is there a way to do this in an automated manner?

Comment: @i.i.k. yes. As the QGIS Raster -> Conversion -> Translate tool uses GDAL internally to convert, you could cut out the middle man and use the [`gdal_translate`](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html) commandline tool with a batch/shell script or in python with the [`osgeo.gdal.Translate`](https://gdal.org/api/python/osgeo.gdal.html) method.  Note: comments aren't for  questions, so if you get stuck  [ask a new question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Comment: @user2856 You are right, I should open a new question. Unfortunately the installation of gdal with the pip-packagemanager failed.

Comment: You can't install GDAL using pip without a compiler and a lot of pain (or knowledge). There's many other ways to install a pre-compiled GDAL.  For example, if you have QGIS you already have GDAL.

Answer (score -3):

To output an raster with data type integer as of type float use the **raster calculator**.

1. execute the trivial expression `"raster@band_no" * 1.0` (replace raster@band_no with an appropriate value or simply double click the entry in the raster channel list)
2. save the output in a format, that supports floating point values, eg GeoTIFF

Comment: Thank you for your help. But it is still not what i'm searching for. With the raster calculator I can get the same data typ like raster -> Conversion -> Translate. Like you sad, I can save as an GeoTIFF (*.tif) but I need it as *.flt. I have no possibility to upload a GeoTIFF in Hec RAS - RAS Mapper.