# "Could not load source layer for INPUT" error when reprojecting flt-file with PyQGIS

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, pyqgis, file-path

The data I have are ESRI Floating Point Data (so they are a raster type). The path I provided is a fake path, so that I don't show my real system paths.

I know that my code works with vector data, as I wrote this script, just for other data-types (*.shp*, *.gpkg*). Therefore, I assume, that the algorithm doesn't work with the flt-type.

... and indeed it doesn't. For reprojecting raster data, there is the algorithm `warp`.

So what I did yesterday was to use batch processing for applying the warp-function to the flt-data. The decision to not adapt the python script to warp the data but to use the batch-processing-functionality was just that it was a good opportunity to try it out (never worked with batches before).

---

I have a couple of .flt-files and I would like to reproject them to another CRS. In QGIS desktop, you can load the *.flt*-files by just dragging and dropping the file.

However, when I try to load the files in PyQGIS it says:

```
Could not load source layer for INPUT: path/to/3257559305385.flt not found
```

My code is just a function which uses the processing module. Is it somehow possible to load .flt-data in PyQGIS?

```py
def reprojectFLTfiles(inputfolderpath, outputfolderpath, crs):
    for fltfile_name in os.listdir(inputfolderpath):
        if '.flt' in fltfile_name:
            if 'xml' not in fltfile_name:
                print(fltfile_name)
                INPUT = inputfolderpath + '/' + fltfile_name
                OUTPUT = outputfolderpath + '/' + fltfile_name
                print(INPUT)
                print(OUTPUT)
                processing.run("qgis:reprojectlayer",
                               {'INPUT':INPUT,
                                'TARGET_CRS':crs,
                                'OUTPUT':OUTPUT
                               }
                )
```

Comment: It seems that the full path to the source file is not being created correctly. What does `inputfolderpath` look like? Does the print statement print the the correct `INPUT` path string? Can you verify it with `os.path.exists()`? As a better practice, I would encourage you to use `os.path.join()` instead of the string arithmetic.

Comment: The path is not the real path but just to prevent to show my system-path in public. I have updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 6):

I would agree with @BenW's comment, that your [binary floating-point files](https://support.geocue.com/binary-raster-files-flt/) can not be found under this path `inputfolderpath + '/' + fltfile_name`. However, I could also say, that your input does not match any of the `INPUT` accepted data types. See, that "Reproject layer" geoalgorithm *reprojects a vector layer in a different CRS*. See the [GDAL Vector drivers](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/index.html) for more details.

⚠️ For raster data types, use the ["Warp (reproject)"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/rasterprojections.html#gdalwarpreproject), see the [GDAL Raster drivers](https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/index.html) for more details.

Your binary floating-point file with a *.flt* extension should come with an ASCII header file that has a *.hdr* extension, see [EHdr -- ESRI .hdr Labelled](https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/ehdr.html). You only specify the *.flt* file; however, there needs to be an existing *.hdr* file in the same directory with the same file name.

---

There are several suggestions to your code:

- check firstly alg input and output by means of the [`processing.algorithmHelp("qgis:reprojectlayer")`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing/console.html#calling-algorithms-from-the-python-console)

  ```py
  INPUT: Input layer

      Parameter type:  QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource

      Accepted data types:
          - str: layer ID
          - str: layer name
          - str: layer source
          - QgsProcessingFeatureSourceDefinition
          - QgsProperty
          - QgsVectorLayer

  OUTPUT: Reprojected

      Parameter type:  QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink

      Accepted data types:
          - str: destination vector file, e.g. 'd:/test.shp'
          - str: 'memory:' to store result in temporary memory layer
          - str: using vector provider ID prefix and destination URI, e.g. 'postgres:…' to store result in PostGIS table
          - QgsProcessingOutputLayerDefinition
          - QgsProperty
  ```
- apply the [`isfile()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.isfile) function from the `os.path` library to check if a file exists

  ```py
  if isfile(INPUT):
     ...
  ```

  Or, as was mentioned by @BenW, apply the [`exists()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.exists) function. This function [`isdir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.isdir) can also be handy for dirs.
- better to work with a normalized path, can be achieved with the [`normpath()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.normpath) function

  ```py
  for fltfile_name in listdir(normpath(inputfolderpath)):
  ```
- two `if`-statements can be combined into one

  ```py
  if '.flt' in fltfile_name and not ('xml' in fltfile_name):
     ...
  ```
- make use of the [`join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) function to get a proper file path

  ```py
  INPUT = join(inputfolderpath, fltfile_name)
  ```
- use the [Python Try Except blocks](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) to handle errors and exceptions e.g. [`QgsProcessingException`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsProcessingException.html).

  ```py
           try:
               params = {
                   'INPUT': INPUT,
                   'TARGET_CRS': crs,
                   'OUTPUT': OUTPUT
               }
               processing.run("qgis:reprojectlayer", params)
               return True
           except QgsProcessingException:
               return False
  ```

  The QGIS processing algorithm also has a [`checkParameterValues()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsProcessingAlgorithm.html#ae3991f84be1b939144df415bec29d3fd)-method:

  > Checks the supplied parameter values to verify that they     satisfy the
  > requirements of this algorithm in the supplied context.
  >
  > The message parameter will be filled with explanatory text if
  > validation fails. Overridden implementations should also check this
  > base class implementation.
- it is not clear yet in which form you provide the `crs` value, but there is a class [`QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.html), that facilitates creation and work with CRS

  ```py
  crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.fromEpsgId(4326)
  ```
- imports can be useful to make your code reusable in the future in standalone applications

  ```py
  # imports
  import processing
  from qgis.core import QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem
  from os import listdir
  from os.path import isfile, join, normpath
  ```
- add some `reprojectFLTfiles` descriptions, see the [PEP 20 – The Zen of Python](https://peps.python.org/pep-0020/) for more inspiration

  ```py
  def reprojectFLTfiles(inputfolderpath: str, outputfolderpath: str, crs: int) -> bool:
      """
      Reprojects a FTL file using a certain CRS
      Parameters:
      ==========
      :param inputfolderpath:
      :param outputfolderpath:
      :param crs:
      Returns:
      ==========
      :return: 
      """
  ```

So, in the end, it may look like this:

```py
# imports
import processing
from qgis.core import QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join, normpath


def reprojectFLTfiles(inputfolderpath: str, outputfolderpath: str, epsg_code: int) -> bool:
    """
    Reprojects FTL file to a certain CRS
    Parameters:
    ==========
    :param inputfolderpath:
    :param outputfolderpath:
    :param crs:
    Returns:
    ==========
    :return:
    """

    crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.fromEpsgId(epsg_code)

    for fltfile_name in listdir(inputfolderpath):
        if '.gpkg' in fltfile_name and not ('xml' in fltfile_name):
            INPUT = join(inputfolderpath, fltfile_name)
            if isfile(INPUT):
                OUTPUT = join(outputfolderpath, fltfile_name)
                try:
                    params = {
                        'INPUT': INPUT,
                        'TARGET_CRS': crs,
                        'OUTPUT': OUTPUT
                    }
                    processing.run("qgis:reprojectlayer", params)
                    return True
                except QgsProcessingException as e:
                    print(f'Could not reproject this {INPUT} file. Ended with the following error:')
                    print(e)
                    return False


reprojectFLTfiles('D:/qgis_test/', 'D:/qgis_test/temp/', 4326)
```

With the code above, I could reproject my GeoPackage from `EPSG:32637` into `EPSG:4326`.

---

**References:**

- [Error: Could not load source layer for INPUT](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/318545/error-could-not-load-source-layer-for-input)
- [Why am I getting 'Could not load source layer for INPUT: invalid value' for native:extractbyexpression algorithm on QGIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67680424/why-am-i-getting-could-not-load-source-layer-for-input-invalid-value-for-nati)
- [Creating flt (floating point raster) with QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/173328/creating-flt-floating-point-raster-with-qgis)
- [QgsProcessingException in Processing script QGIS3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/284644/qgsprocessingexception-in-processing-script-qgis3)

Comment: Thank you so much for the effort! Very helpful, however, I didn't specify the flt-data: it are floating-point-data from ESRI. I updated the question accordingly!